# Django ValidationError for custom model formset with custom fields (data is missing or has been tampered with)

Tags: python, django

I'm working on a model formset for a Membership model (models auth.User membership to app.Project). Here's app/forms.py, after I trimming things I have confirmed to be irrelevant after commenting them out:

```
class EditMembership(forms.ModelForm):
  delete = forms.BooleanField(required=False, initial=False)

  class Meta:
    model = models.Membership
    fields = ('is_owner',)  

  def clean_delete(self):
    return self.cleaned_data['delete']

class BaseEditMemberships(forms.models.BaseModelFormSet):
  # Some custom methods not dealing with validation.
  pass

EditMembershipSet = forms.models.modelformset_factory(models.Membership,
  form=EditMembership, extra=0, formset=BaseEditMemberships)
```

Here is my template:

```
<form method="{{ method|default:"post" }}" action="{{ action }}">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <ul>
  {% for form in formset %}
    <li>{{ form.instance.user}}</li>
    {{ form.as_ul }}
  {% endfor %}
  </ul>
  <input type="submit" value="{{ submit_value|default:"Submit" }}" />
</form>
```

And my view:

```
@ownership_required(message="You must be an owner to edit memberships.")
def edit_memberships(request, pk):
  project = get_object_or_404(models.Project, pk=pk)
  if request.method == "GET":
    formset = forms.EditMembershipSet(
      queryset=project.membership_set.all()
    )
    return render_formset_fullpage(request, formset, "Edit Memberships",
      template=forms.EDITMEMBERSHIPS_PATH)
  elif request.method == "POST":
    formset = forms.EditMembershipSet(request.POST)
    return HttpResponse("Hooray!")
```

And the model in question:

```
class Membership(models.Model):
  class Meta:
    unique_together = ('project', 'user')

  project = models.ForeignKey('common.Project', editable=False)
  user = models.ForeignKey('auth.User')
  is_owner = models.BooleanField(default=False, blank=False,
    help_text="Indicates ownership of the project")
  project_alias = models.CharField(max_length=CHARFIELD_SHORT,
    help_text="User-given name", blank=True)
```

The problem is I keep getting a ValidationError back after doing the POST:

```
ValidationError at /project/4/memberships
[u'ManagementForm data is missing or has been tampered with']
```

From what I can tell, forms.EditMembership is doing OK. I can render that form and recreate it from the POST with no validation error, so I guess it is something wrong with the way I am using BaseEditMemberships/EditMembershipSet.

EDIT:

Just to give you even more information, here are an example form which is generated and the POST vars for one of my test requests. The form:

```
<form method="post" action="">
  <div style='display:none'><input type='hidden' name='csrfmiddlewaretoken' value='d6d535efd35e83076e1ac14a82ef4cdc' /></div>
  <ul> 
    <li>someuser</li>
    <li><label for="id_form-0-is_owner">Is owner:</label>
      <input checked="checked" type="checkbox" name="form-0-is_owner" id="id_form-0-is_owner" />
    </li>
<li><label for="id_form-0-delete">Delete:</label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="form-0-delete" id="id_form-0-delete" />
  <input type="hidden" name="form-0-id" value="8" id="id_form-0-id" />
</li>

  </ul>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Corresponding POST vars if I check the delete box:

- form-0-id: u'8'
- csrfmiddlewaretoken: u'd6d535efd35e83076e1ac14a82ef4cdc'
- form-0-delete: u'on'
- form-0-is_owner: u'on'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include `{{ formset.management_form }}` in your template. See [Django's formset documentation on rendering templates for formsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/formsets/#using-a-formset-in-views-and-templates).